# DYNAMIC SQL FOR TABLE NAME AT RUN TIME

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

```
create or replace procedure ankit
(table_name varchar2)
is 
begin
dbms_output.put('select NAME FROM '||table_name);
end;


begin
ankit('ITEM');
end;
```

I am trying to execute the above command and it's compiling successfully but I am not able to see the output for the same.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT AT US

Comment: :O WHEN DID I SHOUT?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All words in upper case is considered shouting.

Comment: :D well i must welcome myself then :) thanks.

Comment: `SELECT 'It''s not shouting if it''s code!' "Pedantic Comment" FROM dual;` Sorry, couldn't help myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in `SQL*Plus`, then `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` is what you need to do first.

If you are using any `GUI based client tool`, then check the option to **enable** `dbms_output`

And use, `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`

Edit : See this test case.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure ankit
  2  (table_name varchar2)
  3  is
  4  BEGIN
  5  dbms_output.put_line('select NAME FROM '||table_name);
  6  END;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> begin
  2  ankit('ITEM');
  3  end;
  4  /
select NAME FROM ITEM

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable output before running the code in  **SQL * PLUS**

> `set serveroutput on` ;